# What does "bleed" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

What does *bleed* mean in [*I think it's going to be a slow bleed*](http://money.cnn.com/2016/10/06/news/economy/us-growth-gdp-2016/index.html?iid=Lead)?

> The big debate is what will happen next. Will the U.S. economy rebound or will it slide into another downturn?
>
> "I think it's going to be **a slow bleed**," says Lindsey Piegza, chief economist at Stifel. "Right now, we're hoping for 1.5% growth on an annual basis. Next year, we could see 1% growth."
>   She projects the U.S. will "just slowly slide into recession over the next couple of years."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a figurative use of the term ***[bleed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bleed)*** that means:

> - an instance of bleeding; hemorrhage: *an intracranial bleed.*

It refers to the slower and slower pace at with the US economy is growing. The metaphor is that of a human body which becomes weaker and weaker  by slowly losing blood (bleeding).